# Pull csv straight from a web source

Tags: python, pandas

I like plotting my MapMyRun data for fun and its a four-year data set I can use to practice data cleaning. I have to download the csv everytime I go for a run from : https://www.mapmyfitness.com/workout/export/csv

There I login and it downloads. I would like to skip a step and pull it into python immediately and sort it from there, just like I do from github when I pull my csv data. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily for you, your app has its own API. For what I understand of your requirements, a free tier can cover your needs, and you can query your workouts with [this endpoint](https://developer.underarmour.com/docs/v71_Workout/) using [this native python library](https://pypi.org/project/requests/). So, it looks like a pretty straight-forward process. Let me know if you have any difficulty with this or if you need orientation with API consuming.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Do I need to request a "New Partner API Key Request"?

Comment: I see it now. Thank you so much! I have requested my API.